# Combining replace and drag-and-drop in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am creating a quiz-app containing the following entities. There are of course other entities (and properties), but these are the relevant ones:

- **Test** (T) (Id, Name)
- **Question** (Q) (Id, Text, FK_TestId)
- **QuestionLines** (QL) (Id, Text, FK_QuestionId)
- **QuestionOption** (QO) (Id, Text, FK_QuestionId)

T and Q are self-explanatory. QL and QO are described below:

QL1: A cat has ____ legs and ____ tail.

QL2: You have ____ legs.

QOs: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

The user will then drag the QOs (that are draggables) to the right droppable (the underscores/lines).

The format of the QLText (QL entity, Text property) is “A cat has [`<QOId>`] legs and [`<QOId>`] tail”, which will have to be modified before it is presented to the user. So for each [`<QOId>`] a droppable will be inserted instead.

I have tried a filter and a directive, but I end up with the HTML being plain text or at least non-evaluated/compiled AngularJS code and/or droppables that are not bound correct. What I would like, and what the drag-and-drop plugin does, is to bind the ngModel of the draggable (which is a QO object) to the ngModel of the droppable, which is a property (called “objs”) of the QL. The tricky part here (at least for me) is that the “objs”-property has to be an array, since it can have multiple objects bound to it.

When the user presses “Next” to go to the next question, I will save the answer in the following format:

```
[{id: <QLId>, value: [<QOId>]}]
```

So for each QL there will be an object with the id of the QL and an array of the selected QOIds.

I am currently using this drag-and-drop plugin: http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/.

The following is a scraped version of the plain markup:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat=”ql in QuestionLines” ng-model=”ql”>
    {{ ql.QLText }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**So the question is..**

How can i replace the []s with HTML enabling the droppable-functionality and binding the draggable's ngModel to the QL (or the dropppable inside the QL's Text-property)?